# Mongoose.model input sanitization?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
user = new User({
        email: value.email,
        firstName: value.firstName,
        lastName: value.lastName,
        password: value.password,
        isAdmin: value.isAdmin,
        ipAddress: req.ip,
        userAgent: req.get('user-agent')
});
```

This is what I'd like to do in a MongoDB model created via the Mongoose lib. for node.js.

```
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

This doesn't feel safe to me, given that req.ip and the user-agent string could be tampered with client-side.

Is this safe? Does Mongoose sanitize the req. objects for me? Is there a better way to capture the IP address and user agent string?

Comment: it looks fine to me but if you want really high security you could encrypt the sensitive data and each time you fetch it decrypt it again.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if mongoose sanitizes the data for us?

Comment: check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585213/do-i-need-to-sanitize-user-input-before-inserting-in-mongodb-mongodbnode-js-co) at may help