# What javascript input need to be sanitize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security

I have a NodeJs+Express+Mongodb website. I have some input, and I read a lot of things about sanitizing.

Input javascript : handle input client side and display possible page available. When data are correct, suggest a link to redirect client to a page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sort of a duplicate, it would most likely be helpful for you to read it: [Do I need to sanitize user input before inserting in MongoDB (MongoDB+Node js combo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585213/do-i-need-to-sanitize-user-input-before-inserting-in-mongodb-mongodbnode-js-co).

To summarize it, as long as you are not executing direct String input as a direct MongoDB command, you do not need sanitizing. If you were though, sanitization would happen any where that the user can input information that is executed, e.g. forms, search bars, etc.

I hope that helps, if you still have any questions just comment below and I will help you!

Comment: Ok so only input for mongodb, noted !